Wordpress blog post categories redundantly displaying on the same post
Would love any help or advice you may have. Working on a site built with Wordpress that is also using a custom theme. Using Wordpress' CMS, the blog and post section is already set up. Post categories are then manually assigned to each post. I have checked the Wordpress CMS side of things in detail and everything seems correctly set up. Have about 1000 blog posts with various categories assigned to them.


Things on the Wordpress CMS side of things seem to all be correct. Also, the logic of searching by category on the main blog page works as expected. All posts with the assigned category being filtered as expected.
However, when viewing a list of chronological posts on the main blog page, the text fields for assigned categories are not working correctly. Example: 8 posts visually missing a specific tag (though sorting logic still works) and a seemingly random post having that tag applied 9 times in total.

I am fairly confident the CMS is okay. Would love help checking the logic in the .php file:
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cotoacademy.com/web/app/themes/cotoacademy/assets/css/main.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
get_header();
wp_enqueue_script('blog');
get_template_part('template-parts/blog/top-page');
$all_articles_title = get_field('all_articles_title');
$search_placeholder = get_field('search_placeholder', 'option');
$curent_category_name = '';
if (isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
    $catObj = get_category_by_slug($_GET['category']);
    $curent_category_name = $catObj->name;
}
?>

<section class="all-articles last-of-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="all-articles__inner">
                <div class="all-articles__grid">
                    <div class="all-articles__list-block" id="all-posts">
                        <div class="all-articles__list">
                            <?php
                            $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'post_status' => array('publish'),
                                'posts_per_page' => '12',
                                'posts_per_archive_page' => '12',
                                'paged' => $paged,
                            );
                            if (isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
                                $args['category_name'] = $_GET['category'];
                            }
                            if (isset($_GET['date']) && !empty($_GET['date'])) {
                                $date = $_GET['date'];
                                $date_arr = explode('/',$date);
                                $year = $date_arr[0];
                                $month = $date_arr[1];
                                $day = $date_arr[2];

                                $args['date_query'] = array(
                                    array(
                                        'year'  => $year,
                                        'month' => $month,
                                        'day'   => $day
                                    )
                                );
                            }
                            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
                                <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                                    <?php set_query_var('post', $loop->post); ?>
                                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/blog/article-item'); ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <div>Nothing found</div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if ($loop->max_num_pages > 1) :
                            $pag_arg = array(
                                'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
                                'mid_size' => 2,
                                'type' => 'array',
                                'prev_text' => '<span><</span>',
                                'next_text' => '<span>></span>'
                            );
                            if (isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
                                if($_GET['category'] != 'all') {
                                    $pag_arg['add_args'] = array('category' => $_GET['category']);
                                }
                            }
                            $pagination = paginate_links($pag_arg);
                        ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if (!empty($pagination)) : ?>
                            <ul class="all-articles__pagination pagination">
                                <?php foreach ($pagination as $page_link) : ?>
                                    <li class="pagination__item <?php if (strpos($page_link, 'current') !== false) {
                                        echo ' active';
                                    } ?>">
                                        <?php echo str_replace("page-numbers", "pagination__link text__sub-heading--large", $page_link); ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all-articles__search">
                        <?php get_template_part('template-parts/blog/search'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="all-articles__categories">
                        <?php $categories = get_categories(array(
                            'orderby' => 'name',
                            'order' => 'ASC'
                        )); ?>

                        <div class="all-articles__right-column">

                            <div>
                                <div class="all-articles__categories-title text__upper--large">
                                    Categories
                                </div>
                                <ul style="gap: 5px" class="all-articles__categories-list categories-grid">
                                    <li style="contain: strict; border-radius: 8px" data-category="all"
                                        class="categories-grid__item <?= (!isset($_GET['category']) && empty($_GET['category'])) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"
                                        onclick="sort_category(this)">
                                        <img class="categories-grid__img"
                                            src="<?= get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/all-category.png'; ?>">
                                        <div class="categories-grid__name text__upper--large">
                                            All Categories
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                                        <?php if ($category->slug != 'uncategorized' && $category->slug != 'without-category'): ?>
                                            <li style="contain: strict; border-radius: 8px" data-category="<?= $category->slug; ?>"
                                                class="categories-grid__item <?= (isset($_GET['category']) && $category->slug == $_GET['category']) ? 'active' : ''; ?>"
                                                onclick="sort_category(this)">

                                                <?php $image = get_field('image', $category); ?>
                                                <?php if ($image): ?>
                                                    <img class="categories-grid__img"
                                                        src="<?= esc_url($image['url']); ?>"
                                                        alt="<?= esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>">
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                <div class="categories-grid__name text__upper--large">
                                                    <?= $category->cat_name; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/blog/enroll-now'); ?>

                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php
get_footer();
?>



Checked Wordpress CMS
Checked clearing blog and post caches
Checked manually changing a specific post category

Categories are not being displayed on each post but then repeatedly being applied in bulk to a single post.

It sounds like the issue with redundant category display might be due to how the categories are being retrieved or displayed within the article-item template. Here are a few steps to help diagnose and potentially resolve the issue:

Check article-item Template:
Ensure that the article-item template is not duplicating categories when displaying them. Look for the part of the code that outputs the categories and check if there's any loop or function that might be causing the repetition.

Use get_the_category_list():
Make sure you're using WordPress functions correctly to retrieve and display categories. For example, use get_the_category_list() to fetch and display the categories for a post.


Here's an updated version of your article-item template to illustrate how to correctly fetch and display categories:
<div class="post-item">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="post-categories">
        <?php
        $categories = get_the_category();
        if (!empty($categories)) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                echo '<span class="category">' . esc_html($category->name) . '</span>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
</div>


Debug the Categories:
Add debugging output to check the categories being retrieved for each post. This can help you understand if the issue is in the retrieval or the display logic.
  <div class="post-item">
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <div class="post-categories">
      <?php
      $categories = get_the_category();
      if (!empty($categories)) {
          foreach ($categories as $category) {
              echo '<span class="category">' . esc_html($category->name) . '</span>';
              // Debug output
              error_log('Post ID: ' . get_the_ID() . ' - Category: ' . $category->name);
          }
      }
      ?>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
  </div>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>


Check for Custom Functions:
If there are any custom functions or filters applied to categories, review them to ensure they aren't causing the duplication.

Plugins and Theme Conflicts:
Deactivate all plugins except the ones necessary for the blog functionality and switch to a default theme (like Twenty Twenty-One) to see if the issue persists. If the problem goes away, reactivate your theme and plugins one by one to identify the conflict.


If none of these steps resolve the issue, it might be helpful to provide more details about the article-item template or any custom functions related to categories in your theme.
